# Android MediaMetadataRetriever returns null values from most keys

Tags: java, android, metadata, media, android-mediaplayer

I want to get information out of my media files (mp3 mostly) and I get only null from those values I want. I have tried all keys for `extractMetadata(key)`. Am I skipping/missing something?

Code basis:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever f = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
f.setDataSource(item.getFilePath());

String title = f.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
```

I do get correct values with the duration key `(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION)` and mimetype key `(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_MIMETYPE)`, which indicates that the datasource/filepath is working.

Poweramp (popular media player) is able to read metadata values, like title/author/composer etc. since it displays these extra values in the UI. Or perhaps Poweramp gets these values from some other source or method?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what id3 version are your metadata using ?

Comment: Have you being able to do it, Im stuck with this even editing metada by my own using itunes and tag editor free, but get nothing

Answer (score 1):

This may sound silly but have you tried with many different mp3 files? Just with my experience if you get your mp3 files illegally the keys sometimes just aren't there.

Comment: Yea, I test mostly on free podcasts. Poweramp seem to pull out extra information, and I don't know what it does differently.

Answer (score 0):

Poweramp maintains its own database in
/data/data/com.maxmpz.audioplayer/databases/folders.db
You will need a rooted device to investigate this database.
You can send me a pm if you want more details

Comment: I don't want fetch data from one third party app. I'd rather rely on the official API and MediaMetadataRetriever does not seem to work properly. Looking for alternatives if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The meta data value associate with the given keyCode on success; null on failure.