# Android problems with MediaMetadataRetriever: return null value

Tags: android

Trying to retrieve mp3 informations (Albumname,...) with MediaMetadataRetriever.
In the emulator it worked fine. On my device most methods returns null.

MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(songPath);

String albumName = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);

String mp3Title = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);

String mimekey = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_MIMETYPE);

The mp3 has definitly these informtion because in the emulator these information (the same file!) are shown. The file path is ok the mimekey is set and I got no exception.

I'm using SdkVersion=14.
I've checked 
[How to get songs from album/Artist in android,using MediametadataRetriever?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164413/how-to-get-songs-from-album-artist-in-android-using-mediametadataretriever) and 
[Android MediaMetadataRetriever returns null values from most keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465915/android-mediametadataretriever-returns-null-values-from-most-keys)
but it didn't help. Can't debug the MediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata because its native code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you found a solution those many years ago? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: As I mentioned below:  I use the lib org.farng.mp3.MP3File to get these information. Works for my purpose. I didn't find any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever)?:

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(songPath);
String albumName = retriever.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
String mp3Title = retriever.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
retriever.release();
```

Comment: Seeman: Thx for your answer. I tried it now by I didn't get it runable. It seems it is not so easy because I need the libs and you wrote maybe its confusing for those who are unfamiliar the Android NDK. At the moment I haven't the time for further trying.

Comment: Maybe interesting for others: I use the lib org.farng.mp3.MP3File to get these information.

Comment: @SJX, the project comes with prebuilt libraries and , in my opinion, excellent documentation on how to set up and use it. I'm not sure what was confusing.

Comment: I hate the fact MediaMetadataRetriever from the official API is so malfunctional we have to abandon it for a third party alternative such as the one you are recommending. I am gonna have to give it a try. Hopefully it solves my problem.

Comment: @WilliamSeemann This is probably an old post but I am facing same issue as OP. I am wondering that the third party lib you recommended which is essentially wrapper on C/C++ code. Can you suggest which compiled version should be used because I do not know what native architecture my app will run and choosing a particular version might not work every where ? ..

Comment: The project provides AAR's for each architecture so you can generate individual, and thus smaller APK's.

Comment: @WilliamSeemann Any idea why the MediaStore does return values and MediaMetaDataRetriever doesn't? In the docs it says that MediaStore columns return an indexed value of MediaMetaDataRetriever keys. So this is really weird that MediaStore works and retriever doesn't, can you check my post which is a bit more detailed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60957216/why-does-mediametadataretriever-return-null-for-some-keys-but-not-when-i-query-m

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with video GPS_LOCATION. In some of the devices it was working, while in some devices it was not working.

The fix was minor, instead of

```
setDataSource(context, uri)
```

I used

```
setDataSource(absoluteFilePath)
```

Comment: I still have the same problem, still get null values but the weird thing is when i use the MediaStore i'm getting the values i need. Can you check my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60957216/why-does-mediametadataretriever-return-null-for-some-keys-but-not-when-i-query-m

Comment: Actually there is strange behaviour from different devices. Which device are you using, which android version as well ?

Comment: I'm have Android 9 on my real device, but i even tried on emulators with api 21 - 29 and still the same problem across all devices. MediaMetaDataRetriever returns null for some keys, but the weird thing i explained in my post i linked is that it does work with MediaStore columns and these columns return indexed values of MediaMetaDataRetriever keys so i'm really confused why MediaStore works and MediaMetaDataRetriever doesn't because MediaStore returns the same values as MediaMetaDataRetriever.

Comment: There are weird results from different devices. `setDataSource` caused crashed on a huawei phone. So beware that this API is inconsistent across devices.