# Extracting of MetaData with MediaMetadataRetriever has unexpected result

Tags: android, metadata, media, id3

I'm trying to build my own music player for Android.

For a listing I need the metadata of the songs, so I'm using the `MediaMetadataRetriever` to extract them, but the retriever is unable to extract the metadata for most of the songs (~630 of 669). In my PC music software, the metadata are visible and in the Windows Explorer as well. If I open the properties of the songs, I can modify them and if I load the changed files on the phone, it still doesn't work. By the way: If I use any other player on the phone, it is always able to load the metadata.

Is the `MediaMetadataRetriever` buggy and should I use some other libraries for extracting or am I doing something wrong?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465915/android-mediametadataretriever-returns-null-values-from-most-keys) question is related, but doesn't really help to solve my problem.

Here is some of my code as an example:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever lMetaData = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
lMetaData.setDataSource(mAbsolutePath);
mArtist = lMetaData.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
mTitle = lMetaData.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
mAlbum = lMetaData.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
mAlbumArtist = lMetaData.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUMARTIST);
mGenre = lMetaData.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE);
mSongNumber = lMetaData.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_CD_TRACK_NUMBER);
mYear = lMetaData.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_YEAR);

if(mArtist == null)
    mArtist = new String("");
if(mTitle == null) 
    mTitle = new String("");
if(mAlbum == null) 
    mAlbum = new String("");
if(mAlbumArtist == null) 
    mAlbumArtist = new String("");
if(mGenre == null) 
    mGenre = new String("");
if(mSongNumber == null) 
    mSongNumber = new String("");
if(mYear == null) 
    mYear = new String("");
```

Comment: I just use another external library for the tags, so the problem is some kind of solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MediaMetadataRetriever only supports a handful of formats. I recommend [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever). It supports several additional formats and protocols.