# Android: Retrieve music file information from raw folder

Tags: android, cursor, uri, android-mediaplayer, android-contentresolver

I am trying to retrieve information about a music file in my raw folder.  I need to retrieve the duration, title, artist, etc.  I understand how to retrieve this information for music files stored in external storage but I do not know how to for music files in the raw folder.  Help and links would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching around and trying the below examples, I was unsuccessful.  @Jignesh Shaw's solution gave me an IllegalArgumentException when I would set the MediaMetadataRetriever's source and @Hanz Kratz's solution was only able to extract the song's duration (as he described)

Between the two, however, I was inspired to come up with a working solution.

```
Uri mediaPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.song_name);
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(this, mediaPath);
```

Information could then be extracted just as both users had stated

```
String sponsorTitle = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
String sponsorArtist = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
//and so on...
```

I have no idea why this works perfectly but @Hanz Kratz's solution does not.  If other people stumble upon this thread it would be nice if you posted your findings.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Just get the `FileDescriptor` for the raw asset, and then use the `MediaMetadataRetriever` to extract metadata such as duration, etc.

```
    MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    FileDescriptor fd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.rocknroll).getFileDescriptor();
    mmr.setDataSource(fd);
    String duration = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
```

This works fine for duration but unfortunately the `MediaMetadataRetriever` has issues for artist, title, ... with some MP3 files: [Android MediaMetadataRetriever returns null values from most keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465915/android-mediametadataretriever-returns-null-values-from-most-keys)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  You pushed me in the right direction (see my edit for the correct answer)

Comment: Great! You should extract your answer from your question though, post it as answer and accept it. It is perfectly fine to self-answer questions on SO and accept them.

Answer (score 0):

this may help:-

```
String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
 String[] projection = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
         MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
         MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
         MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION};

 cursor = this.managedQuery(
         MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, selection,null, null);

 private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();

 while(cursor.moveToNext()){
     songs.add(cursor.getString(0) + "||" + cursor.getString(1) + "||" +
             cursor.getString(2) + "||" + cursor.getString(3) + "||" +
             cursor.getString(4) + "||" + cursor.getString(5));
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this is not what I'm looking for.  As stated in the question I already know how to retrieve information from files located in external storage.  I am trying to retrieve information about a file in the raw folder

Answer (score 0):

Load the path of your resource like this:

```
String mediaPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://<your-package-name>/raw/filename").getPath();
```

Make sure you don't append the file extension. For example use "filename" and not "filename.mp3"

You can then access ID3 tags (assuming you are using mp3 files) like this:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(mediaPath);

String albumName = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
```

and so on..

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help, your answer pushed me in the right direction (see edit for the correct answer)